# A link problem with Windows 7 shell functions

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, linker

I'm trying to enumerate files through the Windos 7 library API, e.g. with **SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder**

I'm using a C++ win32 console application and getting link errors, e.g.,

```
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DSA_DestroyCallback@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl DSA_DestroyCallback(struct _DSA *,int (__stdcall*)(void const *,void *),void *)" (?DSA_DestroyCallback@@YAXPAU_DSA@@P6GHPBXPAX@Z2@Z)
```

These errors appear even if I only `#include <ShlObj.h>`

Should I add some specific library to the linker inputs?
Thanks, R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for [`DSA_DestroyCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775655(VS.85).aspx) states that you need to link against Comctl32.lib.

Comment: It links, thanks. Then at runtime I get an error "the ordinal 346 could not be located in the dynamic link library CMCTL32.dll"

Comment: @robi: you probably have a version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The linker can't find DSA_DestroyCallback. That function is in `Comctl32.lib`. Did you include that import library?

(Add `#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")` if you are on MSVC)